# What ajax toolkit zimbra 6.x is using ? kabuki or YUI

Tags: yui, webclient, zimbra

i`m trying to customize the zimbra web client and do changes.my question is, what Ajax toolkit zimbra is using ? yahoo user interface ? or kabuki ?

Answer (score 1):

So far I can remember it is Kabuki.

Comment: i cant find any folder that named "kabuki" but there is folder with name "YUI" in `jetty\webapps\yui`, is there any suggestion ?

Comment: can go through the links:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zimbra


http://www.sitepoint.com/zimbra-ajaxtk-a-toolkit-for-ajax-powered-guis/


http://www.zimbra.com/community/kabuki_ajax_toolkit_download.html